# Qt event override QEvent::KeyRelease only happens once

Tags: qt, events, qaction

I have a Qt 5.4 application targeted for Ubuntu. I am trying to make a physical key do the same thing as a control on the touch screen. I am using a QAction. The touch is activated thru a signal/slot, I am trying to get the physical key activated through action->trigger();.

In it, I have a parent class derived from QDialog that overrides event:

```
class MyParentDialog : public QDialog
{
...
protected:
   virtual bool event (QEvent *event);
...
}
```

And the class derived from it with a problem that also overrides event:

```
class MyChildDialog : public MyParentDialog
{
...
protected:
   virtual bool event (QEvent *qEvent);
...
}
```

Implementation:

```
bool MyChildDialog::event (QEvent *qEvent)
{
qInfo()<<"MyChildDialog::event"<< qEvent->type();

switch (qEvent->type ())
{
    case QEvent::KeyRelease:
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvt = nullptr;
        keyEvt = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent *>(qEvent);
        int key = keyEvt->key();
        switch(key)
        {
        case KEY_CH1ON:
        {
            qInfo()<<"MyChildDialog::event KEY_CH1ON";
            bool currCheck = m_pActionRun->isChecked();
            m_pActionRun->trigger();
            bool afterCheck = m_pActionRun->isChecked();
            qInfo()<<"MyChildDialog::event KEY_CH1ON" 
               <<currCheck<<afterCheck;
            return true;
       }

        default:
            return MyParentDialog::event(qEvent);
        }
    }
    return true;

    default:
        return MyParentDialog::event(qEvent);
}

return true;
}
```

If I comment out the line "m_pActionRun->trigger();", I get all events expected (qInfo() observation). If I include that line, I get all events until after the first KEY_CH1ON. After that, I only get paint events. The same action code works as expected repeatedly when activated through the touch screen signal/slot mechanism.

I am fairly new to Qt. Am I missing a trigger reset or something?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: The issue is that MyChildDialog loses focus when the action is triggered. If I press the hard key (KEY_CH1ON) again, the event goes to the parent of MyParentDialog. If I press the touch screen and then KEY_CH1ON again, MyChildDialog gets focus and gets the event as expected.  I am running thru options, activateWindow(), setFocus(), at the end of the action slot code, but not working yet without the manual touch.

Answer (score 0):

In these instances I typically emit a signal and connect it to a slot to trigger the action. Queue the signal/slot so that it won't run synchronously and can be called safely from another event trigger.

Add a signal to your class header:

```
class MyParentDialog : public QDialog
{
...
signals:
    void triggerMyAction();
...
}
```

In the constructor (once m_pActionRun is created) add:

```
connect(this, &MyParentDialog::triggerMyAction, m_pActionRun, &QAction::trigger, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Finally, in `MyChildDialog::event` instead of calling trigger directly, emit the signal:

```
emit triggerMyAction();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it, the behavior is the same as m_pAction->trigger(). I will keep looking and reply if I figure it out.

Comment: MyChildDialog is losing focus when the action is triggered. I wrote a more expansive comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something about invoking the action or within the action itself caused MyChildDialog to lose focus. Pressing the touchscreen gave it focus and all the appropriate events again.  My workaround was to add a "active child dialog" member to the main application. Since I am just working with key **releases**, I added a hack to the key **press** code in the main application to reset focus to MyChildDialog (when the flag is set).